# Find index from row and column

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing, row

I'm trying to populate a master array based on corresponding values to the rows and columns.

E.g. If 80 matches a value in the first column and 120 matches value in first row. Insert a value into that index.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5XjA.png)

How can this be done?

The end goal is to populate this table by extracting the max value from many files and using the values corresponding to the columns and rows in the main array to find the indexes and store this max value there.

Is this on the right path or my thought process way off and should be using different logic?

Thanks

Comment: You can use something like `find(A(:,1)==80)` for the row index and `find(A(1,:)==120)` for the column index

Comment: Try use sparse matrices.

Comment: Please, you are at least a bit of a software person if you are asking in stackoverflow. You must be aware how useless it is data/text on images. Add them as text

Comment: Hi Steve I'm not sure how that would work as I would then have two instead of one.

Hi Ander for more background I have a array e.g. 2x8

MastArray = [0,0,20,40,60,80,100,120;5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

by finding values in another file by indexing them corresponding to a max number e.g. "test" = max(A)

B = position(test) 5
C = speed(test) 60

using these values I need to find the index where both of these are true in the MastArray. So I can insert "test" in that position.

If this makes sense?

Comment: You would save them as e.g., `ii` and `jj`, then access `A(ii,jj)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question completely, but here is a way to achieve the insertion.

As [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5358968/steve) suggested, this can be done using `find`. (see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) for documentation)

```
MastArray = [0,0,20,40,60,80,100,120;80,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

[~,c] = find(ismember(MastArray(1,:), 120));
[r,~] = find(ismember(MastArray(:,1), 80));

MastArray(r,c) = 42;
```

There is probably a better way to do this, but this is the simplest solution I could come up with now.